# JQuery find which one is visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<select id="milesAway">
    <option id="5" value="5">5 miles</option>
    <option id="10" value="10">10 miles</option>
    <option id="25" value="25">25 miles</option>
    <option id="50 value="50">50 miles</option>
    <option id="100" value="100">100 miles</option>
    <option id="250" value="250">250 miles</option>
    <option id="500" value="500">500 miles</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="zipCode" />
<input type="text" id="cityState" class="cityState" />
```

So at any point in time, only one of these 3 available inputs will be shown. They are all controlled by `.show()` and `.hide()`

I do I use JQuery to find out which one is the one that is shown and get it's id.

Thanks!

Comment: keep in mind that `.show` and `.hide` will not work in Internet  Explorer (*all versions*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do

```
$(':input:visible') //This will selects all inputs on the page. You can narrow this down by specifying an ID that wraps the input you are looking or.
```

You can also check if input is visible by doing

```
$('#cityState').is(':visible')
```

Comment: Won't that work on every input on the page though? I want it to be limited to these three things.

Comment: Is there any way I can use the 3 id's to limit it down to only these 3 things/

Comment: @scott yes. I have it in my answer. You can put the Id's in separated by a comma. In my answer i have the elements separated by comma, just replaces them by the id's

Comment: You mean `$('#milesAway , #zipCode , #cityState').filter(':visible')`? `is()` will only return a true/false.

Comment: @bazmegakapa Depends on how you want to use the selector.

Comment: @Hussein: that's true, but next to it you wrote in the comment: `This will only select the one that is visible`. I just said no, it will not select it, it will just tell whether there is at least one visible element from the 3 or not.

Comment: Yes you're right, i was writing and i had another selector in mind.  Check the note above the selector. it say "check if selector is visible".

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/RSGrW/1/

First update after reading comments:

```
var id = $("#milesAway:visible option:selected, #zipCode:visible, #cityState:visible").attr('id');
```

Because I saw you put the ids inside the option, I figured you would like that returned. This is the alternative for just the input or select id.

```
var id = $("#milesAway:visible, #zipCode:visible, #cityState:visible").attr('id');
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('option:visible');`

would match all option elements that are not hidden, by hidden I mean display:none, I don't think visibility:hidden counts! you would have to double check this in the jQuery documentation under the "Selectors" section

Answer (score -1):

Here ya go:

```
$('select:not(:visible)');
```

I'd suggest adding a class to each of the elements to easily select them:

```
$('.toggleInputs:not(:visible)');
```

Comment: Open up developer console on this page and run:

$('div:not(:visible)');

Comment: would toggleInputs be the class name?